# Make drop down menu go back up when clicking anywhere else on the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I had some work done on a site and the developer didn't finish the job so I need some (probably) basic code to finish this off.

Basically I need a drop down box to go back up once a user clicks anywhere else on the page. At the moment it just stays dropped down until you click the menu item again.

Here is the code I have taken from the site:

```
<li class="gendb1" id="gnrl" onclick="gen();" >GENERAL</li>
<li class="gendb" id="dbid" onclick="Db();">D&B</li>
<script>
   function gen()
   {           
      var div = document.getElementById("txt");
      var txt = document.getElementById("txt2");
      if (div.style.height == "0px") {
         txt.style.height = "0px";
         div.style.height = "230px";
      }
      else {
         div.style.height = "0px";
      }   
   }

   function Db()
   {     
      var div = document.getElementById("txt2");
      var txt = document.getElementById("txt");
      if (div.style.height == "0px") {
         txt.style.height = "0px";
         div.style.height = "320px";
      }
      else {
         div.style.height = "0px";
      }           
   }
</script>

<div id="txt">
   <span style="display: block; margin-top: 29px;">Some text</span>
</div>
<div id="txt2">
   <span style="display: block; margin-top: 29px;">Some other text</span>   
</div>
```

Any help would be great. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are probably a number ways to accomplish this. The below snippet contains one method that will "close" the boxes when anything but their "trigger" is clicked. This code also removes the `onclick="gen();"` and `onclick="Db();"` scripts from your list item html code and the subsequent functions from the JavaScript code that is not needed.

Hope this helps.

```
// NEW JAVSCRIPT CODE
<script>
document.addEventListener("click", function dropToggle(event) {
  "use strict";
  var target = event.target || event.srcElement;
  var txtOne = document.getElementById("txt");
  var txtTwo = document.getElementById("txt2");
  var txtOneTrigger = "gnrl";
  var txtTwoTrigger = "dbid";
  var targetID = target.id;
  switch (targetID) {
    case txtOneTrigger:
      txtTwo.style.height = "0px";
      if (txtOne.style.height !== "0px") {
        txtOne.style.height = "0px";
      }
      else {
        txtOne.style.height = "290px";
      }
      break;
    case txtTwoTrigger:
      txtOne.style.height = "0px";
      if (txtTwo.style.height !== "0px") {
        txtTwo.style.height = "0px";
      }
      else {
       txtTwo.style.height = "320px";
      }
      break;
    default:
      txtOne.style.height = "0px";
      txtTwo.style.height = "0px";
      break;
  }
});
</script>
```

---

**SNIPPET**

```js
document.addEventListener("click", function dropToggle(event) {
  "use strict";
  var target = event.target || event.srcElement;
  var txtOne = document.getElementById("txt");
  var txtTwo = document.getElementById("txt2");
  var txtOneTrigger = "gnrl";
  var txtTwoTrigger = "dbid";
  var targetID = target.id;
  switch (targetID) {
    case txtOneTrigger:
      txtTwo.style.height = "0px";
      if (txtOne.style.height !== "0px") {
        txtOne.style.height = "0px";
      }
      else {
        txtOne.style.height = "290px";
      }
      break;
    case txtTwoTrigger:
      txtOne.style.height = "0px";
      if (txtTwo.style.height !== "0px") {
        txtTwo.style.height = "0px";
      }
      else {
       txtTwo.style.height = "320px";
      }
      break;
    default:
      txtOne.style.height = "0px";
      txtTwo.style.height = "0px";
      break;
  }
});
```

```css
/* This CSS is just for demonstration purposes only */
#gnrl, #dbid {outline:solid green 1px;}
#txt, #txt2 {outline:solid red 1px;}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li class="gendb1" id="gnrl">GENERAL</li>
    <li class="gendb" id="dbid">D&amp;B</li>
</ul>
    <div id="txt">
       <span style="display: block; margin-top: 29px;">Some text</span>
    </div>
    <div id="txt2">
       <span style="display: block; margin-top: 29px;">Some other text</span>   
    </div>
```

Comment: Is it possible to also have it so that if the item is clicked again it will also close?

Comment: @CalverDesigns - I updated the code to close the targeted dropmenu if it is open already.

Comment: @CalverDesigns - Updated: removed some unnecessary code.

Comment: Now that is EXACTLY perfect! Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Add this.

```
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```